# $\int_{T_pM}\phi\ dx = \int_M \lambda^{-d}\phi(\lambda^{-1}\exp_p^{-1}(\cdot))\ dV_g$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $r>0$ be its [injecitivity radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#I), $p$ be a point on $M$. Let $\phi:T_p(M)\to \mathbf R$ be a function supported in 
$$B_{T_p M}(0_p,r):=\{X\in T_p M:\|X\|_g<r \}.$$
It is easy to see that the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)) $\exp_p:B_{T_p M}(0_p,r)\to M$ is a diffeomorphism to its image.
Then the following family of scaling functions of $\phi$ is well-defined on $M$,
\begin{align}
\phi_p^\lambda(q):= 
\begin{cases}
\lambda^{-d}\phi(\lambda^{-1}\exp_p^{-1}(q)), & q\in \exp(B_{T_p M}(0_p,\lambda r)), \\
0, & \text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases} \quad \lambda\in (0,1]
\end{align}

> **My question is:** does the following equality holds
>   $$\int_M \phi_p^\lambda\ dV_g = \int_{T_pM}\phi\ dx?$$
>   Here $dV_g$ is the [volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form) on $M$, $dx$ is the lebesgue measure on $T_pM$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is simply derived as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_M \phi_p^\lambda\ dV_g &= \int_{\exp(B_{T_p M}(0_p,\lambda r))} \lambda^{-d}\phi(\lambda^{-1}\exp_p^{-1}(q))\ dV_g(q) \\
(x=\exp_p^{-1} q) &= \int_{B_{T_p M}(0_p,\lambda r)}\lambda^{-d}\phi(\lambda^{-1}x)\ dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^d \\
(v=\lambda^{-1}x) &= \int_{B_{T_p M}(0_p,r)}\phi(v)\ dv \\
&= \int_{T_pM} \phi(v) dv.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Note that in the second equality, we used the [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates), then $g_{ij}(x) = \delta_{ij}$.